# IE not positioning absolute div

Tags: internet-explorer, html, positioning

On [this link](http://www.pelicanworldwide.com), you will see that the flags and the top image are correct in FF but not on IE7-8.  Why? Is there something missing for container?

```
#container { min-width:1024px; max-width:1024px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; } 
#bannerFlag { position:absolute; top:8px; margin-left:36px; } 

<div id="container">
<div id="bannerFlag">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see a difference on my computer. Maybe add `position:relative;` to `#container` ?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to link a site to stackoverflow, instead take a screenshot and upload that.